# Python config.py file in an Azure function

Tags: python, azure, azure-function-app

In my config.py file, I have this and I need it in order to run my function app.

```
'headers' : {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded', 'Cache-Control': 'no-cache'},
    'locallogdir': r'',
    'azure_config' : {
        'driver' : '{ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server}',
        'server' : '',
        'UID' : '',
        'PWD' : '',
        'database' : ''
        },
```

Where/how would I put it into my Azure FunctionApp? Does it go into the settings.json and if so, how? I tried to put it in there and it didn't work.

Answer (score 2):

You need to keep them as [`AppSettings`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-app-settings). You can add these settings under the Function [`App settings`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-how-to-use-azure-function-app-settings#settings), Here is the complete [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-reference-python#environment-variables)

```
import logging
import os
import azure.functions as func

def main(req: func.HttpRequest) -> func.HttpResponse:

    # Get the setting named 'myAppSetting'
    my_app_setting_value = os.environ["myAppSetting"]
    logging.info(f'My app setting value:{my_app_setting_value}')
```